# WordPress minify JS & CSS with minit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, minify, codex

I'm not good wordpress developer.

I want to use [minit](https://github.com/kasparsd/minit/blob/master/minit.php) plugin with redux framework. I’ve added minify js, minify css options on my theme option panel. If i enable minify js option, theme minify only js files, if i enable minify css option, theme minify only css files. But [minit](https://github.com/kasparsd/minit/blob/master/minit.php) plugin minified js & css files. How can i minify in each case.

```
if( $redux_option['minify_js'] ) {
    add_filter( 'minit-exclude-js', 'custom_minit_exclude_js' );
} else {
    remove_filter( 'minit-exclude-js', 'custom_minit_exclude_js' );
}
if( $redux_option['minify_css'] ) {
    add_filter( 'minit-exclude-css', 'custom_minit_exclude_css' );
} else {
    remove_filter( 'minit-exclude-css', 'custom_minit_exclude_css' );
}
```

This code not work on my theme. Do you have solution.
Need your help
Thanks.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with the code you posted. Do you have these callback functions too?

Comment: Yes. I've added callback function.

Comment: So what exactly do you want? Do you want them to only be operational 1 at a time? Or can they just run both at the same time?

Comment: I used this guide https://github.com/kasparsd/minit/wiki

Comment: @DaMaGeX I want to only minify JS files or CSS but plugin minified both CSS, JS files.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if( $redux_option['minify_js'] && !$redux_option['minify_css'] ) {
    add_filter( 'minit-exclude-js', 'custom_minit_exclude_js' );
} else {
    remove_filter( 'minit-exclude-js', 'custom_minit_exclude_js' );
}

if( $redux_option['minify_css'] ) {
    add_filter( 'minit-exclude-css', 'custom_minit_exclude_css' );
} else {
    remove_filter( 'minit-exclude-css', 'custom_minit_exclude_css' );
}
```

Now if minify css is enabled, minify js won't work. You can also do it the other way around.